# Error logging for PHP API deployed in AWS Ec2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS Ec2 instance to place my API written in PHP.Right now i have used Log4PHP for error logging.I want to know any other built in Error Logging facilities available for AWS Ec2.?

Comment: I use rollbar personally, so does the SaaS company I work for, this is really opinion based though. For internal logging I've literally just used php's inbuilt logging for the last 16 years when it's been required

Comment: AWS would tell you to use CloudWatch, but I don't see the point in it

Answer (score 0):

Ec2 has nothing to do with your application logs, it's something that totally depends on the application logic. *you application write logs and cloud service ship the logs* The most common way of writing logs

- Push logs to stdout/stderr
- Write logs to log file

The first approach is recommended approach in cloud environment plus this is also  base on [The twelve-factor app](https://12factor.net/)

> A twelve-factor app never concerns itself with routing or storage of
> its output stream. It should not attempt to write to or manage
> logfiles. Instead, each running process writes its event stream,
> unbuffered, to stdout. During local development, the developer will
> view this stream in the foreground of their terminal to observe the
> app’s behavior.

[XI Logs: Treat logs as event streams](https://12factor.net/logs#:%7E:text=Treat%20logs%20as%20event%20streams&text=In%20server%2Dbased%20environments%20they,running%20processes%20and%20backing%20services.)

You can use [PHP Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), which also suggested by [AWS PHP logging article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/php-application-logging-with-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-and-monolog/)

> PHP Monolog is a standards-compliant PHP library that enables
> developers to send logs to various destination types including,
> databases, files, sockets, and different services. Although PHP
> Monolog predates the standards for PHP logging defined in PSR-3, it
> does implement the PSR-3 interface and standards.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/php-application-logging-with-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-and-monolog/) is the details article to check about integration of the library with different framework.

[image]

Also, rollbar can be considered as suggested in the comment, its environment independent and you use this any platform but its not free and you can trial with limited log stream.